# Xilinx ISE 9.2i setup error

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise

every time I try to setup Xilinx 9.2i the installation stops at 99% and a message appears from Windows says the program has stopped what should I do ?

Comment: Get a more recent release.  The version i have is 14.7, so i'm guessing 9.2 is pretty old.

Comment: You could try to install without selecting the usb/cable drivers.  Or as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

9.2 was made for xp 32 bit.  I have recently tried to install this in win 10.  I ran into the same issue as you.  I fixed this by using a VM Box running a 32 bit version of windows 7.